# List of all tables used in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I need the simplest way to get all table names used in MySQL query

```
"select * From Tab1 " $result= Tab1
"select * From Tab1, Tab2 Where ID1=ID2" $result= Tab1, Tab2
"delete From Tab1" $result= Tab1
```

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this other than writing your own SQL parser.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `EXPLAIN` for `SELECT` statements - simply prepend `EXPLAIN` keyword in front of your query and execute it. It will give you MySQL query execution plan, which will also include list of tables involved - check out this **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a47b2/1)**.

It should also work For `DELETE` statements, but beware that it may actually delete rows as side effect, which may not be desirable for your task.

Comment: Very smart hack indeed, [but unreliable](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a47b2/13), unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php function mysql_info which return information about last query executed.

```
string mysql_info ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

Answer (score -1):

i'm not completely sure about your intention but to list all tables from a database simply execute the following command

```
SHOW TABLES from 'dbname'
```

Comment: This shows list of all tables in mysql database, but OP asked for list of tables referred in given SQL statement